# рекурсия в php копировалось с начальной папки

Tags: php, рекурсия

Проблемма такая есть скрипт он работает, но не совсем так как нужно. Скрипт рекурсивно копирует папки из одной директрории в другую, но проблема что он копирует содержимое папки. Тоесть есть папка А и В в папке А  лежат папки C и D так вот если привыполнении скрипта присходит следующие я копирую папку А в папку В то в папкке В попадают папки C и D а я хочу что бы в папку B попала папка A со своим содержимым вот мой код

```html
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}
$tekstDst = $_POST["path"];
$tekstDst = substr($tekstSrc,2)."/";
$tekstDst = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$_POST["address"].$tekstDst;//папка в которую всё копируется


$tekstSrc = $_POST["folder"]; // что будет копироваться
foreach ($tekstSrc as $tekstSrcs) {
    $tekstDst = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$_POST["address"].$tekstSrcs;

    recurse_copy($tekstSrcs, $tekstDst);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите копировать вложенные папки, надо добавить проверку на это условие

```
function recurse_copy($src,$dst, $level = 0) { // тут
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) && $level == 0) {  // тут
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file, $level++); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}
```

Comment: не подходит так он просто копирует ту папку в которую копируется